# arrays using python

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays. query_array and stem_array.
stem_array has elements in format (word | synonyms). the query_array has words in it.

I want to check if the query_array has words that are contained in the synonyms part of the stem_array and if yes, then map the synonym to the actual word.

for eg: query_array (presidential, authenticity) 
stem_array (president | presidential , authentic | authenticity, authentication)
so my final array should return (president and authentic).

please help me as i am new to python and i have a project to complete.

thanks.

Comment: Is your data literally in that format? For example a string "(president | presidential)"

Comment: Paste real code. The "arrays" you described make no sense.

Comment: @yakiimo: yes. it is literally in this format.

Comment: Also how big are your synonym word sets?

Comment: check out python dictionaries: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: There are no arrays in Python, do you meant `list`s?

Comment: Are you aware of how to make the algorithm in the first place and just need the code, or are you lost on the whole thing?

Comment: @yakiimo: the list is quite big. i am totally lost. please help me.

Comment: @julio.alegria: yes. i mean lists.

Comment: @ghbhatt, I think I or someone else gave you what you need? Please select a solution or let us know what else you need. Also, please get going on some python tutorials :) [Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) might be good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are totally lost here and do it step by step so you can figure out how to do it in the future. But it sounds like you need to do some python tutorials. All of this is untested code.

Get the queries in a reasonable format:

```
query_string = query_array[1:-1] #remove the parentheses with slicing
queries_with_whitespace = query_string.split(",") #split the string into a list
queries = [query.strip() for query in queries_with_whitespace] #remove whitespace
# queries = [item.strip() for item in query_array[1:-1].split(",")] #all in one
```

Same for the synonyms. Here is for one of your stem strings:

```
def stem_and_syns(unformatted_string): #unformatted string is your stem_array
    stem_string = unformatted_string[1:-1] #same as before
    stem, synonyms_string = stem_string.split("|") #split the stem and synonyms
    stem = stem.strip() #clean the stem
    synonyms = [synonym.strip() for synonym in synonym_string.split(",")] #same as before
    return stem, synonyms
```

But you need synonyms to be in a reverse lookup. Do you realize that for any given word, it could be a stem as well as a synonym? And that any word could have multiple stems? You need to figure out what to do in that case. Anyway, here is the reverse lookup:

```
stem_lookup = {}
for stem_string in stem_strings #stem_strings is the set of all of your non-formatted stem strings
    stem, synonyms = stem_and_syns(stem_string)
    for synonym in synonyms:
        #point all synonyms to a list of possible stems
        stem_lookup.setdefault(synonym, []).append(stem)) #make a new list if this synonym not used yet
```

Finally, with the queries from the beginning (again, this makes one set of assumptions that are easy for me, but may not meet your needs):

```
result = [stem_lookup.get(original,original) for original in queries] #uses original itself if it's not a synonym
```

Answer (score 2):

Expand the stem array into a dictionary, so that every is a key in the dictionary and the value is a list of all its synonyms:

```
stem_dict = {
    'presidential': ['president'],
    'president': ['presidential'],
    'authentic': ['authenticity', 'authentication'],
    'authenticity': ['authentic', 'authentication'],
    'authentication': ['authentic', 'authenticity'],
}
```

now the answer for any word is just a `stem_dict[word]`.

It look like each synonym list is a string with separators, so use string.split to break them up so you can put them in the dictionary.